# What's the colimit of the n-sheet covering spaces over the circle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I was thinking in computing the filtered colimit of the n-sheet covering spaces $f_n: \mathbb{S}^1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ ($f(z) = z^n$) in the comma category of topological spaces with the transition mappings $g_n: \mathbb{S}^1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ ($g_n (z) = z^2$) between $n $ and $2n$. It looks like this is well defined and that the colimit exists (and maybe it's the universal covering), however I have no idea how it is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, it is called the solenoid.

Comment: @studiosus You mean the standard real line covering?

Comment: No, it is a certain compact space. It has to be compact as a closed subset of a product of circles.

Comment: @studiosus So, I don't know what you mean by solenoid.

Comment: Just google it or check Wikipedia (make sure read the mathematical description). The definition is the one you gave; Wikipedia will list some properties. In any case, this is surely not the line since solenoid is compact.

Comment: @studiosus sorry, but I think it would be the filtered limit (if it commutes with the other coverings, which I think that fails) and not the colimit.

Comment: can you explain what category this is and why $1 : S^1 \to S^1$ is a map between $n$ and $2n$ ?

Comment: I see that I missed the word "filtered" in the question. I do not know what such colimits are, which means that I have no further comments for now.

Comment: @mercio as i said it's the comma category of topological spaces over $\mathbb{S}^1$ and i thought the identity could connect the coverings $f_n$ and $f_{2n}$ since I don't know how to pass from an arbitrary $m > n$.

Comment: @studiosus it's the directed limit (and it's a colimit, it's confusing!).

Comment: I asked you to give details because I went to wikipedia and apparently I need three categories and two functors to make sense of "the comma category of topological spaces". Now maybe you meant the slice category over the circle in the category of topological spaces ?

Comment: @mercio Yes, it's a particular case of comma category.

Comment: Then $1$ is not a map from $f_n$ to $f_{2n}$ because if it was, you would have $f_n = f_{2n} \circ 1 = f_{2n}$

Comment: @mercio You're right. I was thinking geometrically in maintain the fiber by the map (but it's not enough). I've edited to correct it.

Comment: Your arrows are the wrong way around. $f_{2n} = f_n \circ (z \mapsto z^2)$ so this is a map from $f_{2n}$ to $f_n$

Comment: @mercio Yes, I messed it again. But my intention was to define a map to the other direction ($n$ to $2n$), so I don't know how to define it. I would appreciate if you have a solution to it. My intention was to get a kind of $z^{\infty}$.

Comment: My intention was to find a "weak" universal covering and then see if it is simply connected and then try to generalize this to arbitrary covering spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my intention in defining a colimit is impossible. If $f: \mathbb{S}^1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ is such that $f_n \circ f = f_m$, then it defines a lifting, but this is only possible when $m \mathbb{Z} ={f_m}_{*} (\pi(\mathbb{S}^1)) \subset {f_n}_{*} (\pi(\mathbb{S}^1)) = n\mathbb{Z}  $, i.e, $n |m$ , therefore $m \leq n$ always happens. Hence such morphism connecting each covering spaces in an increasing order cannot exist.

By the other side, the limit exists being induced by $g_n(z) = z^2$. But $n \geq 1$, therefore the filtered limit is the 1-sheet covering $f_1: \mathbb{S}^1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$.